# DownladAsyncFile checking the file download completion

Tags: c#

Is there any way to know which file has just now finished downloading  from the DownloadFileCompleted event of  WebClient.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UserState` to do this. Something like this

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadDataCompleted +=
         new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadDataCompleted);

client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("YourURL"), "YourIdentifier");
```

Handler

```
static void client_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)  
{
    var calledBy = e.UserState; //This will be "YourIdentifier"
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

When downloading file use webClient.DownloadFileAsync(uri, name, state) method.
This 3rd parameter (state) will be sent to your in the UserState property of the DownloadFileCompleted event arguments.

Just pass the uri or the file name there and you will have it back nicely :)